# Apply XMP photo manipulation in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, image-manipulation, xmp

I want to automatically manipulate images with ImageMagick (or any other tool that can be run on an Ubuntu server or called via an API). In order to get exactly the result I want, I have tinkered with Photoshop and exported the XMP metadata to document the manipulation. It looks like this:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c007 1.136881, 2010/06/10-18:11:35        ">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
    xmlns:crs="http://ns.adobe.com/camera-raw-settings/1.0/"
   crs:Version="7.0"
   crs:ProcessVersion="6.7"
   crs:Sharpness="38"
   crs:LuminanceSmoothing="0"
   crs:VignetteAmount="-17"
   crs:VignetteMidpoint="32"
   crs:SplitToningShadowHue="0"
   crs:SplitToningShadowSaturation="0"
   crs:SplitToningHighlightHue="0"
   crs:SplitToningHighlightSaturation="0"
   crs:SplitToningBalance="-15"
   crs:ParametricShadows="-14"
   crs:ParametricDarks="-16"
   crs:ParametricLights="+4"
   crs:ParametricHighlights="+31"
   crs:ParametricShadowSplit="25"
   crs:ParametricMidtoneSplit="50"
   crs:ParametricHighlightSplit="75"
   crs:SharpenRadius="+0.5"
   crs:SharpenDetail="100"
   crs:SharpenEdgeMasking="17"
   crs:PostCropVignetteAmount="0"
   crs:GrainAmount="24"
   crs:GrainSize="2"
   crs:GrainFrequency="6"
   crs:LensProfileEnable="0"
   crs:LensManualDistortionAmount="-2"
   crs:PerspectiveVertical="0"
   crs:PerspectiveHorizontal="0"
   crs:PerspectiveRotate="0.0"
   crs:PerspectiveScale="100"
   crs:Exposure2012="-0.05"
   crs:Contrast2012="0"
   crs:Highlights2012="+27"
   crs:Shadows2012="+18"
   crs:Whites2012="+29"
   crs:Blacks2012="+1"
   crs:Clarity2012="+6"
   crs:ToneCurveName2012="Linear"
   crs:LensProfileSetup="Auto"
   crs:HasSettings="True">
   <crs:ToneCurvePV2012>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </crs:ToneCurvePV2012>
   <crs:ToneCurvePV2012Red>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </crs:ToneCurvePV2012Red>
   <crs:ToneCurvePV2012Green>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </crs:ToneCurvePV2012Green>
   <crs:ToneCurvePV2012Blue>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </crs:ToneCurvePV2012Blue>
  </rdf:Description>
 </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

Now I would like to apply exactly the same manipulation with a tool that can be run server-side. Is it possible ? Can I achieve exactly the same result with ImageMagick ? Does Photoshop expose an API, or maybe a SDK allowing me to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a pretty massive ask of **ImageMagick** to achieve identical results, or even close, to those achieved by Photoshop.

Adobe puts **massive** development effort into ACR (Camera Raw) and things like lens profiles require vast amounts of testing and management of databases of lens characteristics on different cameras which are just not part of the remit or objective of ImageMagick.

Also, ImageMagick delegates the RAW processing to `UFRAW` and I don't believe that supports advanced features like "Clarity" and "Luminance Smoothing".

Photoshop does expose an API which is scriptable - [Adobe Photoshop Scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) in JavaScript, AppleScript and VBScript.

Comment: Can Photoshop be installed on Windows Server ? Say I want to process one photo per second, can I run multiple instances of Photoshop on the same host  to handle the load ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Photoshop to answer that, though I would doubt you can run multiple instances in parallel. I would suggest you click `edit` under your original question, and add in the text of your comment above for all to see.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this for RAW photos is to use the free Adobe DNG Converter (available for both Windows and macOS, but the Windows version might run with wine).

When you ask it to convert a RAW to a DNG you can have it embed a full size JPEG preview in the DNG. It will respect whatever settings are in the XMP when generating the JPEG preview. You can ask it to convert a DNG to a *second* DNG as a way to update the embed preview. And it works from the command line.

Then use something like ExifTool to edit the XMP metadata, and to extract the embed JPEG preview.

I've used this with reasonable success to create a barebones RAW converter:
https://github.com/ncruces/RethinkRAW